# running "virtual" database in Java code with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I used to run my Java code with Hibernate to mysql.

Some logical changes led me to decide that I don't need to save the data in the database, but in java class that will handle it as a database (The data is delete in every startup of the application).

How can I do in Hibernate? is there a way to create an in memory database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to:

- add the driver for the database you want to use and change the hibernate settings for this driver,
- change the setting hibernate database dialect,
- change the jdbc connection String
- (add the jars for the database)

For example for [Hypersonic H2 Database](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html):

- driverClassName = org.h2.Driver
- dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
- connection string = jdbc:h2:mem:test

Comment: The access to h2 performance wise is the same as accessing mysql?

Comment: I think this depends highly on your data and usecases. -- I use H2 to run my "unit"-tests, and this is faster than MySQL, but indeed this is a very special use case.

Answer (score 3):

Consider H2 (recommended) or HSQLDB. You can certainly use Hibernate with them. In fact, HSQLDB was the database used by default in Hibernate for their test suite (I think they just changed to H2).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/).

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [SqlLite](http://www.sqlite.org/), which is an in-memory database.  I'm just about to start using it with NHibernate for the same purpose in unit tests.